# Error sending email to alias with Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, gmail, alias

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 64bit.

I'm trying to set up Postfix on my VPS, which has been configured but when I send an email to an alias e.g. `webmaster@domain.com` it will send it to `myemail@hotmail.co.uk`. Now when I sent the email from my GMail account, I got this returned:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

    webmaster@domain.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 #5.1.0 Address rejected webmaster@domain.com (state 14).

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
       d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
       h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
       bh=R1WtjVRWywfkWCR2g4QKbSjAfUaU9DAAMKbg9UAWqvs=;
       b=FiSfdhEaV4pEq/76ENlH4tvOgm35Ow3ulRg06kDYrIQTaDf3eOEgfSEgH25PjZuAj/
        7Hg1CL++o6Rt/tl80ZiR2AWekhA0zIn2JkqE7KssMG7WbBmMmbf8V9KDo2jOw+mZv+C/
        KDKsQ65AudBZ/NYLDDpTT7MkKf8DzqeGCKj9MAct6sHDoC0wCciXYxNfTf+MKxrZvRHQ
        oICTkH5LOugKW9wEjPF2AoO8X0qgYmTLYeSUtXxu46VeNKRBGmdRkkpPOoJlQN9ank7i
        SW6kU6M9bk2bYOgKwV/YPsaantmYlu1XdmYx+kWeJkNJAyYOfXfZZ8WUJhbbFFD9bZCi
        m/hw==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.101.3.5 with SMTP id f5mr783908ani.86.1334247306547; Thu, 12
 Apr 2012 09:15:06 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.236.73.136 with HTTP; Thu, 12 Apr 2012 09:15:06 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Thu, 12 Apr 2012 17:15:06 +0100
Message-ID: <CAN+9S2aB=xjiDxVZx3qYZoBMFD4XuadUyR_3OYWaxw1ecrZmOQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Test Email
From: My Name <myemail@gmail.com>
To: webmaster@domain.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001636c597eabfd21504bd7da8fd
```

Now that I don't understand why it isn't working, my aliases are set up correctly - I see no error messages being produced in `/var/log/mail.log` or any other mail logs, which makes it harder for me to debug.

This is my postfix configuration (`postconf -n`):

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = localhost
mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24 127.0.0.0/8
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Does anyone know how to solve this specific issue?

EDIT:

I found this in my mail log (`/var/log/mail.log`):

```
Apr 13 21:56:03 giTzor postfix/smtp[22260]: 12E761796006: to=<myemail@hotmail.co.uk>, orig_to=<developer@mydomain.com>, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.120]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0/0.01/0.64/0.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <4f875bf3cd801@mydomain.com> Queued mail for delivery)
Apr 13 21:56:03 giTzor postfix/qmgr[1773]: 12E761796006: removed
```

EDIT:

This is the MX records at GoDaddy:

[image]

EDIT:

I've edited my A records and MX records:

[image]

[image]

I can send emails to my aliases with Google Mail, but I can't seem to receive emails from other sites such as Facebook, Yahoo, etc - even Hotmail accounts.

Comment: Is `mydomain = domain.com` the actual config, or did you mask the domain name?

Comment: I replaced my real domain with `domain.com` because I do not want to show it on SF.

Comment: Sure, just making sure you did change it from the default.  Otherwise that would be part of the issue :-)

Comment: Well? Could you help anything further?

Comment: If I had another idea, I'd post it.

Comment: @KyleSmith I have edited my post, maybe it'll help?

Comment: Can you double check the mx dns records for your domain, and that they point to your VPS?

Comment: There's something not right.  Both gmail and hotmail are mentioned, but hotmail is the final address.  I smell a bad relay setup somewhere.

Comment: @ChristopherEvans I provided my screenshot of GoDaddy with my domain.

Comment: @ChristopherEvans I have a new update on my post.

Comment: @ChristopherEvans Hola, have you got any updates for me?

Comment: With your latest update, does google work or not? Which domains can send to your webmaster@domain.com email account, and which can't?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run [newaliases](http://www.postfix.org/newaliases.1.html) ?

Comment: Yup. Even reloaded and restarted postfix - nothing changed.

Comment: Well? Could you help anything further?

Comment: No, because you are not providing the actual domains facing the problem. It seems that the problem is hidden in some detail which we cannot guess unless we have the actual data to help you.